# Givens transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors in $\Bbb R^m$. How can we come up with an algorithm using Givens transformations which computes an orthogonal $Q$ such that $Q^Tx=y$?

Any help with this problem will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extending $\{x\}$ to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, namely $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ where $x=x_1$. (This can be accomplished using Gram-Schmidt.) Now, let $x_1^T,\ldots,x_m^T$ form the rows of an orthogonal matrix $Q(x)$, in that order. Note that $$Q(x)^Te_1=x_1=x.$$

Now, suppose that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ are unit vectors. We then have $$y=Q(y)^Te_1$$ $$=Q(y)^T(Q(x)^T)^{-1}x$$ $$=Q(y)^TQ(x)x$$ $$=(Q(x)^TQ(y))^Tx.$$ Therefore, your desired $Q$ is $$Q:=(Q(x)^TQ(y))^T$$

Comment: I have to do this using Givens transformation.